# Tabular Recta table not generating correctly

Tags: c

I am building a tabula recta table for a vigenere cipher and for some reason it is printing `'@'` instead of `'a'` after the first loop. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
    char alph[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char tRecta[26][26] = {0};  //Tabular Recta

    int i,k,j = 0;
    for(i=0;i<26; i++) { //Build tabular recta
        for(k=0; k<26; k++) {
            if((j+k) > 26) {
                tRecta[i][k] = alph[(j+k)-26];
            } else {
                tRecta[i][k] = alph[(j+k)];
            }
        }
        j++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<26;i++) {
        for(k=0;k<26;k++) {
            printf("%c",tRecta[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is what I am getting:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@b
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@bc
efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@bcd
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@bcde
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@bcdef
hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@bcdefg
ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@bcdefgh
jklmnopqrstuvwxyz@bcdefghi
klmnopqrstuvwxyz@bcdefghij
lmnopqrstuvwxyz@bcdefghijk
mnopqrstuvwxyz@bcdefghijkl
nopqrstuvwxyz@bcdefghijklm
opqrstuvwxyz@bcdefghijklmn
pqrstuvwxyz@bcdefghijklmno
qrstuvwxyz@bcdefghijklmnop
rstuvwxyz@bcdefghijklmnopq
stuvwxyz@bcdefghijklmnopqr
tuvwxyz@bcdefghijklmnopqrs
uvwxyz@bcdefghijklmnopqrst
vwxyz@bcdefghijklmnopqrstu
wxyz@bcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
xyz@bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
yz@bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
z@bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
```

I have not used C much before, is `printf("%c",tRecta[i][k]);` not doing exactly what I think it is doing?

Comment: Don't use magic numbers! What`s wrong using the sizeof the array as limit?

Comment: I suggest if((j+k) > 25) {  instead of if((j+k) > 26) {, that should fix things

Comment: I suggest change the variable declaration to: char alph[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access to your array out of bounds. Change `if((j+k) > 26)` to `if((j+k) >= 26)`., becaus the last valid index for array `alph` is `25` and not `26`. An other solution would be to use `%` operation:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 26

int i,k,j = 0;
for( i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++ ) { //Build tabular recta
    for( k=0; k<ARR_SIZE; k++ ) {
        tRecta[i][k] = alph[ (j+k) % ARR_SIZE ];
    }
    j++;
}
```

Note you read `alph[26]`. This is undefined behaivor.

Comment: Thank-you, why does it print @ in my original code? if it accesses the 27th element of alph

Comment: @user3831011 `alph[26]` is th first byte in memory after your array `alpha`. In your case it is randomly `@`, but this is undefined behaivor.